# Emulating ActiveX communication with Excel

Tags: c#, excel, crystal-reports, com, activex

We use an application which uses Crystal Reports to display some reports.

The application also has a button which exports the report to Microsoft Excel. However, this does only work if Excel is installed on the same machine as the program is executed.
We cant install Excel on the server for licensing reasons.

From the error message `Error 429: ActiveX component can't create object` I assume that the application is using COM/ActiveX to communicate with Excel.

Is it possible to write a C# program to emulate the COM interface of excel?

Comment: I doubt this has anything to do with Crystal, there is going to be custom code that uses Excel to generate the data - The error looks like it comes from VB6 or VBScript code.  There are other ways to create Excel documents from .Net without the need for Office such as EPPlus - None of these will be COM compatible drop-ins for the Excel application itself.

Answer (score 0):

The Crystal runtime can export to excel without any need for Excel to be installed. This means the application you use is probably doing something extra with Excel. Consider contacting the company that developed the software and ask them to address your question.